# Do something when an Entity's attribute is modified

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

**Context**

Imagine I have a Railway network: `Station` are linked together by `Rail`.

- I need to do periodic maintenance on the Rails (I have a `Maintenance` Entity).
- `Station` Entity can be destroyed by setting the `destructionDate` attribute to something different than NULL.
- There is a "ManyToMany with attributes" relationship between 2 `Stations`, defined in the Entity `Rail`
- I need to track which `Station` has been connected/disconnected to which `Station` and when, so in my `Rail` Entity I have a `connectionDate` and a `disconnectionDate` attribute.

**What I want to do**

- When I disconnect 2 Stations (i.e. `$rail->setDisconnectionDate(now())`), the corresponding `Maintenance` Entities are deleted.
- When I destroy a Station (i.e. `$station->setDestructionDate(now())`), the corresponding `Rail`s are disconnected (i.e. `$rail->setDisconnectionDate($station->getDestructionDate`) AND the corresponding `Maintenance` Entities are deleted.

**How to solve that**

For the moment, I trigger events in my controllers' Actions and it works fine. But the problem is that they are many ways in my application to disconnect 2 Stations or destroy a Station and not all of hen go through the Controller. I need to be sure not to miss a Station destruction or a Rail disconnection.

So I was thinking about trigger event in the Entity, for example in the `setDestructionDate()` method. I search the web and apparently this is not a good idea.

I wanted to use Doctrine postUpdate events, but they are triggered even if the destructionDate is not modified. I could filter it but I'm not sure this is the best thing to do.

So, how would you solve that problem? What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 2):

you could create EventSubscriber and listen to either preUpdate or onFlush event.
in preUpdate you have access to what has changed.

for example:

```
class YourEventListener implements EventSubscriber {

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            Events::preUpdate => 'preUpdate'
        );
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs){
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();

        if($entity instanceof Rail){
            if($eventArgs->hasChangedField('disconnectionDate')){
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and register the subscriber `$em->getEventManager()->addEventSubscriber(new YourEventSubscriber());`.

Comment: I didn't know about this `$eventArgs->hasChangedField(...)` method, that's pretty usefull. But I'm still not sure about the frame of this Subscriber: will the `preUpdate` function (as your described above) be executed on **any** entity update? Or only the entity of the same bundle?

Comment: its for every entity.